# firebase cloud functions Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

when i want to update Cloud Firestore from Realtime Database i deployed bellow code and i get error.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const firestore = functions.firestore;

exports.onUserStatusChange = functions.database
    .ref('/status/{userId}')
    .onUpdate(event => {

        var db = admin.firestore();


        //const usersRef = firestore.document('/users/' + event.params.userId);
        const usersRef = db.collection("users");
        var snapShot = event.data;

        return event.data.ref.once('value')
            .then(statusSnap => snapShot.val())
            .then(status => {
                if (status === 'offline'){
                    usersRef
                        .doc(event.params.userId)
                        .set({
                            online: false,
                            last_active: Date.now()
                        }, {merge: true});
                }
            })
    });
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
    at exports.onUserStatusChange.functions.database.ref.onUpdate.event (/user_code/index.js:18:20)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you got the code for a beta version of Cloud Functions for Firebase. The syntax has changed in the 1.0 version. From the [documentation on upgrading your Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database):

or onWrite and onUpdate events, the data parameter has before and after fields. Each of these is a DataSnapshot with the same methods available in admin.database.DataSnapshot. For example:

> Before (<= v0.9.1)
>
> ```
> exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((event) => {
>   const beforeData = event.data.previous.val(); // data before the write
>   const afterData = event.data.val(); // data after the write
> });
> ```
>
> Now (>= v1.0.0)
>
> ```
> exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((change, context) => {
>   const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the write
>   const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
> });
> ```

So you will want to use:

- `.onUpdate((change, context) => {` to declare the funtcion, instead of `.onUpdate(event => {`
- use `change.after` to refer to the data, instead of `event.data`
- use `change.after.ref.once('value')`, instead of `event.data.ref.once('value')`

Since it seems that this code is mostly copied from somewhere, I'd recommend getting an updated version from there. For example, the Firestore documentation that your code is likely based on, contains an up-to-date example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#updating_globally

Comment: thank u @Frank, what about this line  event.params.userId

Comment: On the same page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_properties_for_user_auth_information

Answer (score 0):

Try to change below code, as firebase functions on events have two properties any more. So, ref position is:

```
.onUpdate((event,context) => {
 ....
return event.ref.once('value')
...
```

`event.data` does not exist anymore, instead `event.val()` for [more info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and `event` has [properties like](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot)

Comment: sorry i have same issue

Comment: The remain `event` properties need to update `event.params.userId` to `context.auth.uid` so on. Try to update all. (Try to console.log the event, context and snapshot properties)

Comment: the error in this code functions.database.ref('/status/{userId}')

Comment: i get this code from this tutorial everything is work just function is not working [link](https://blog.campvanilla.com/firebase-firestore-guide-how-to-user-presence-online-offline-basics-66dc27f67802)

Comment: Here the link, you may use the same mission. This is client-side code. So, you may solve it with it too. Or convert it at cloud functions if you want to use in server side.: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

Comment: @user3903484 Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: So, you want online offline at server side or client side?

Comment: i developed chat application using flutter i want to know the user is online or offline i find this tutorial [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/fmanaging-user-presence-with-firestore-in-android-a1146bdf101d) now everything is working just cloud function is not working also i test this [link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/9e3b35bb17519bcbf4bfe4906f0af3d1897f882d/presence-firestore/functions/index.js#L18-L58)

Comment: Ok. I will update the code above after a while. This code will be client side. But honestly the link I gave upside is ready to use code. just you need to change the paths

Comment: Don't forget the code will be client side. Not server side. So, code will be executed at user's device, and you need to include the code at your javascript code. Which will be executed when user uses the app. :) Hope its clear !. If not please re ask to avoid wasting time!

Comment: yes i know as i said everything is working just cloud function is not working

Comment: No, you didn't understand or I could not explain good: 1. aim is to know a user online or not ? so I will solve this not with cloud function.

Comment: If the aim is only to find out whether user online or offline, you do not need to work with cloud function!

Comment: so how you solve it, now when he user closed the app will automatically show me offline the problem is i use Cloud Firestore, the Cloud Firestore not have function onDisconnect  just firebase database have this function so i want when user offline just update Cloud Firestore user collection to offline

Comment: @Frank has explained above very good. ! Then I gave up to update the code.