# Cannot read property ref of undefined and Firebase upgrade on Win 10

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have two Firebase Cloud functions, one is written in "old" version, and one -- in "new":

```
exports.recountTotalCalories = functions.database.ref('/mealsOf/{userId}/{day}/meals/{mealId}')
    .onWrite(
        async( change ) => {
            const collectionRef= change.after.ref.parent;
            const counterRef= collectionRef.ref.parent.ref.child('totalCalories');
            let finalSum = await (collectionRef.ref.once('value').then( (snap) => {
                let sum= 0;
                snap.forEach( (child) => {
                    console.log(child.val().numCalories);
                    sum= sum+parseInt(child.val().numCalories);
                })
                return sum ;
            }));
            return await counterRef.set(finalSum);
        }
    );

exports.updateColors = functions.database.ref('/mealsOf/{userId}/{day}/totalCalories')
.onWrite(
    async(change,context) => {
        const rootRef = change.after.ref.root.child('userInfo/'+context.params.userId);
        let calorieLimit = await rootRef.once('value').then( (snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
        });
        let totalCalories = change.after.val();
        const collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent.ref.child('meals');
        return await collectionRef.ref.once('value').then ( (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach( (child) => {
                console.log(totalCalories);
                console.log(calorieLimit);
                child.redZone = totalCalories > calorieLimit;
                console.log(child.redZone);
            });
        });
    }
);
```

The first function works fine, it is the second that gives me trouble by saying "cannot read the property ref of undefined", which I found out by exploring the logs in Firebase console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
    at exports.updateColors.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/index.js:105:47)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:756:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/
```

So, a certain SO thread [firebase cloud functions Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800984/firebase-cloud-functions-cannot-read-property-ref-of-undefined) recommends "upgrading" Firebase cloud functions. But I am not sure just how. I have tried issuing the commands suggested here: [Firebase functions: cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647170/firebase-functions-cannot-read-property-user-id-of-undefined) on my machine (Windows 10), it seemed to have done some work, but the error persists on the Realtime Database. What am I missing?

EDIT: the log entry refers to line `const collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent.child('meals');`, and even more precisely -- to `change.after.ref`. But We are already accessing this in the beginning of the function, why does not it complain about it then?

EDIT': Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  }
}
```

EDIT'': I re-wrote my second function using `async` (see the update above) and now it seems to execute all-right, except that the log is full of false promises and the desired change is not made to the database, anyway:
[image]

EDIT''': Now, this is the latest version of my second function, which finally does the trick:

```
exports.updateColors = functions.database.ref('/mealsOf/{userId}/{day}/totalCalories')
    .onWrite(
        async(change,context) => {
            const rootRef = change.after.ref.root.child('userInfo/'+context.params.userId);
            let calorieLimit = await rootRef.once('value').then( (snapshot) => {
                return snapshot.val();
            });
            let totalCalories = await change.after.ref.once('value').then((snap) => {
                return snap.val();
            });
            const collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent.ref.child('meals');
            return await collectionRef.ref.once('value').then ( (snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach( (child) => {
                    console.log(totalCalories);
                    console.log(calorieLimit);
                    child.ref.child('redZone').ref.set(totalCalories > calorieLimit);
                    console.log(child.val());
                });
            });
        }
    );
```

Getting the hang of JavaScript is tricky, it seems.